# javascript metacharacters lower case letter

Tags: javascript, metacharacters

Assign re with a regular expression that contains a lower case letter(a-z) followed by a comma

This is the question and I wrote

```
var re =/[\Sa-z]/
```

and it is not working.

Is there special metacharacter for lower case letter?
and what does it mean followed by a comma? how do I do that?

Comment: add the context you are using it in. What doesn't work? What is the issue? What is actually happening?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need anything beside the a-z and the ,

```
/[a-z],/
```

https://regex101.com/r/kuHbSR/1